# Background color changes while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

I was randomly browsing the net when I chanced upon this site:

http://www.libertyinnorthkorea.org/summit/

I was intrigued by how the background color changes while scrolling down the page. As a newbie web developer I want to inquire if you guys know how it was programmed, did they used JavaScript, flash and PHP? Do you guys have any sample code for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage questions to show some evidence of research on the asker's part. What have you tried?

Comment: You may want to look at parallax scrolling, then modify existing parallax techniques to change background colors.

Comment: That is a pretty cool website actually. It isn't as difficult to emulate as it may look. Just listen for a scroll event, and animate the background color. You could use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.onscroll` event and `body.scrollTop` property in javascript.